# Changed MongoDB port but still tries default port

Tags: database, mongodb

I changed the port in the  /etc/mongod.conf file ie

```
net:
  port: 12345
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,123.123.23.255 #localhost and server pub ip
```

Then I restarted mongo

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod.service
```

and checked all ok:

```
sudo systemctl status mongod

mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-07-10 13:35:14 UTC; 16s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 1927 (mongod)
    Tasks: 23
   Memory: 136.3M
      CPU: 1.240s
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
           └─1927 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Then I tried to login to mongo:

```
mongo --username me --password my_password --authenticationDatabase authdb
```

And got the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-07-10T13:29:14.716+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-07-10T13:29:14.717+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
```

I then changed the port back to 27017 in mongod.conf and could login to the db OK.

Any idea why the mongo shell tries 27017 even though mongo port is changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing between mongo server (the server you configure when you change .conf file) and mongo client you used to connect to mongo server. If you changed your port to 12345, then you must precise it when you try to connect, providing it in the connecting command :

`mongo --username me --password my_password --authenticationDatabase authdb --port 12345`

or

`mongo --username me --password my_password --authenticationDatabase authdb --host 127.0.0.1:12345`

EDIT : without any port specification in mongo command, default one will be used, so 27017.

Comment: Thanks, as per here http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.3/driver/reference/connecting/connection-settings/ Without any arguments, constructing a MongoClient instance will connect to “localhost” port 27017.